# SASS Scout app File to import not found or unreadable

Tags: css, sass, scss-lint, scout-sass

I successfully installed sass and started work on it everything was ok an then this happened

> File to import not found or unreadable: layout/_blog.scss

Parent style sheet: 
main.scss

```
29: @import 'layout/_footer.scss';
30: @import 'layout/_blog.scss';
31: @import 'layout/_mobile.scss';
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Could you post your file structure? I'm guessing it's an issue with file paths.

Comment: Kevin can you please check this screenshot http://prntscr.com/g3h92y

Comment: Your file structure looks correct. Looking around through SASS forums, it appears that this is a known bug. I believe that a workaround is explicitly using the full path name for `layout/_blog.scss`. Example: `C:/User/Project/scss/layout/_blog.scss`

Comment: i did this but still same error

Comment: Maybe try updating the version of scss-lint (though at this point I'm kind of grasping at straws for what could be wrong)